# How to interpret the PHP time() function

Tags: php

Every time a user uploads a new picture, we rename the picture to the value of PHP's `time()` function, so our database doesn't have duplicate picture names (because there is no same year, month, day, hour, min and sec).

I need to know whether or not the value of `time()` includes the year. If not, then next year will allow duplicated picture names. How do I understand the return value of `time()`, for example 1301888225? How do I get year, month, day, etc. information out of that number?

Comment: always check the http://php.net/ manual, crystal clear there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo date("d.m.Y H:i:s", 1301888225);

//04.04.2011 03:37:05
```

Unix timestamp will work on 32bit machines until January 19, 2038 so you can safely name your pictures for a long time. What if 2 users upload a picture at the same second?

```
$filename = time()."_".mt_rand(0, 9999).".jpg";
```

Comment: I suggest `<user-id>_<time-stamp>_<random-no>.<ext>` for filename if you're saving the file to directory structure.

Comment: @Amil Waduwawara, I have added added random number to demonstrate.

Comment: @webarto the random number can return the same number twice. Unlikely, but very possible.

Comment: Just add another 9 and it will be more unlikelier :) It is possible.

Comment: @Amil, since we have unique user-id, why we still need random-no? Is it just to avoid duplicate pic name when a user upload multiple pictures at the same second? How can a user upload multiple pictures at the same second? It is very impossible. LOL.

Comment: @zac, you don't. There's no reason for it if you use user-id (assuming it's unique). As noted by **alex**, the random number has it's own conflicts, so it's worthless IMO. It's not that the same user can upload multiple pics, it is that multiple users can upload pics at the same second.

Comment: @Jason McCreary, true, but also depends on directory structure, if each user has it's own folder, than timestamp + random number is opposite of worthless.

Comment: @webarto, even in that case, a random number provides no additional value as it has potential conflicts. If users had their own directory, then a timestamp is enough. Theoretically a user can not or *should* not be uploading something at the exact same time. Bottom line, appending a random number is not a solution in this case. It only makes a conflict less likely. Not avoids one. That's weak sauce. Built it right the first time.

Answer (score 3):

`time()` returns the current Unix timestamp.

- It does include year information
- You can pass it to many of the [PHP date functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.datetime.php), such as `date()` to output time however you want

Read the more about the [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

Comment: I saw the page that u showed me before, so the algorithm for value of time() is week x  hours x mins x seconds. So does it mean time() is not include the information of year? So next year the picture name will be duplicated?

Comment: There is no algorithm, that is number of seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT. A simple counter.

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the manual:

```
int time ( void )
```

> ```
> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the
> ```
>
> Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00
>   GMT).

So you don't have to worry about the duplicated name issue.  However, you should be aware of [the year 2038 problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Comment: Actually I saw the info but i don't understand the sentence "measured in d number of sec since the unix epoch...". But now I understand it, all thanks to @webarto's answer above : "that is number of seconds from January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT. A simple counter".

Answer (score 0):

What if two users upload a file in the same second? Why don't you just use the temporary name PHP assigns to the file?

Comment: what is the usage for temporary name? How it works? I am thinking about rename picture start from 1, 2nd picture name as 2, 3rd picture name as 3. So when a user upload a new picture, mysql need to check the name of latest picture. Let's say the latest picture name is store in variable $lstname, the new picture must be renamed as $lstname+1

Comment: em, if two users upload the picture at the same time, mysql get the name of new picture at the same time, then the name of the 2 new pictures will be the same too? OMG.

Comment: @Zac when you upload check `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` from memory. I believe the possible problem is known as a *race condition*.

Comment: @zac1987, to avoid possible problems add a random number to filename. Look in my answer.

Comment: Hei, finally I found the best solution. Since all user has unique username, I can use $new-pic-name = $username . time(); so when there are multiple users upload picture on the same seconds, their picture name also cannot be the same because the picture name consist their unique username.